# Configure screen button events

Tags: abap, dynpro

How to configure a save button in order to press it and the info that is entered on the screen to be saved in a specific database table?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Where is this button, in alv, in dynpro screen ? Is the db table a sap table or it is in other independent database ?

Comment: Its in dynpro screen, the table is an internal table that I created on my own to store the data thats gained from a join that I did

Answer (score 1):

When you double clicked your button in the layout screen, you will see and fcode area that[image] you should give a function name.

Then in the screen PAI events user comment section, you can define the what button will do. You should modify your db table, under that button fcode name case. [image][image]

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3LlNo20t5E) is a tutorial about module pool development.

You can check these links for table control tutorials: [1](http://saptechnical.com/Tutorials/ABAP/TableControl/Index.htm), [2](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Learn+Making+First+Table+Control).

Comment: in this case I'm trying to Save the information that I've written in the corresponding fields of the dialog box. (Id CODE ,Name,Surname) When I click the button I need that info to be registered on my table control.
Thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: Edit your question then, because it says, modifying a database table, not a table control.